# Elements not being displayed for flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a 2 column layout with a fixed width on the left and a flexible right column that fills the remainder of the screen. The columns are not being display.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left-column {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.right-column {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-fixed-flex

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-fixed-flex-yp3gyc?file=style.css

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign height and `flex-direction:row;` and for a fixed width, `left-column` supposed to have a width as well.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `flex-direction: row;`? That's the default. The `height: 100vh;` is the answer, although maybe not the best one (see dupe).

Comment: You're right @ggorlen